# Subsetting glyphs in opentype feature sets to reduce webfont filesize

Tags: unicode, fonts, webfonts, opentype

Many webfont generation tools such as fontsquirrel.com's [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), or myfonts.com's webfont kit builder allow a subset of the font's glyphs to be selectively exported on the basis of either ASCII characters or unicode values or tables.

Is there a way to similarly select and export only a handful of opentype ligature glyphs (or glyphs from other OT features such as stylistic/contextual alts) that do not have assigned unicode values?

The aforementioned tools export webfonts with opentype features by providing checkboxes to include the entire character set, or the entirety of a feature set ("Contextual Alts" and/or others).

In cases such as rendering known headlines or logotypes where say, a subset of letters, plus one or two common and/or discretionary ligatures are needed, a font containing its entire character set is unnecessarily heavy in filesize and a wasteful download for users.

Is there a way to create a webfont with limited opentype glyphs that can be used in browsers that support:

```
font-feature-settings: "liga"; /* or "dlig", "swsh", "smcp", etc. */
```

and thus can automatically render "fi" as its ligature *ﬁ* or do other opentype magic if the right glyph is included?